How to display lots of data with ListView/GridView at realtime
I have to visualize lots of messages from a CAN bus systen with my app.
My app uses C#, WPF and MVVM. To display the data I implemented an Usercontrol, that uses a ListView with a GridView as View element. To have auto sizing for the columns of the GridView, I'm using the so called AutoSizingGridView like described here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5275925/Auto-Sizing-WPF-GridView-Class.
Here is a the ListView part from my MessageListBox.xaml:
        <ListView x:Name="ListView"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding VirtualizingCollection}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
                  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DataTypeConverter}}"
                                     Value="{x:Type viewModel:StringMessageViewModel}">
                           <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource StringMessageRowTemplate}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DataTypeConverter}}"
                                     Value="{x:Type viewModel:CanMessageViewModel}">
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CanMessageRowTemplate}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <autoSizingGridView:AutoSizingGridView IsValueTrackingEnabled="True">
                <!--<autoSizingGridView:AutoSizingGridView IsValueTrackingEnabled="True">-->
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" Width="Auto" >
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Entry Id" Visibility="{Binding Settings.ShowId, Converter={StaticResource TrueVisibleElseCollapsedConverter}}"
                                              behaviors:GridViewBehaviours.CollapseableColumn="True" MinWidth="50">
                            <TextBlock Text="#" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Timestamp, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}}" Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Timestamp of message" Visibility="{Binding Settings.ShowTimestamp, Converter={StaticResource TrueVisibleElseCollapsedConverter}}"
                                              behaviors:GridViewBehaviours.CollapseableColumn="True" MinWidth="120">
                            <TextBlock Text="TimeStamp" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PortName}" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Connection Port Name" Visibility="{Binding Settings.ShowPortName, Converter={StaticResource TrueVisibleElseCollapsedConverter}}"
                                              behaviors:GridViewBehaviours.CollapseableColumn="True" MinWidth="100">
                            <TextBlock Text="Port" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DirectionCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Direction&#x0a;&lt;- In&#x0a;-&gt; Out">
                            <TextBlock Text="&lt;-&gt;"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource SourceCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Source">
                            <TextBlock Text="Src" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DstCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Destination">
                            <TextBlock Text="Dst" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource LenCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Length of MessageData">
                            <TextBlock Text="Len" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource CcCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Command Class">
                            <TextBlock Text="CC" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource CnCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Command Number">
                            <TextBlock Text="CN" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource PidCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Process Id" behaviors:GridViewBehaviours.CollapseableColumn="True"
                                              Visibility="{Binding Settings.ShowPid, Converter={StaticResource TrueVisibleElseCollapsedConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="PID" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource CsnCellTemplate}" Width="{StaticResource ByteHeaderColWidth}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="Command Subnumber">
                            <TextBlock Text="CSN" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataCellTemplate}" Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader ToolTip="User Data">
                            <TextBlock Text="Data" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </autoSizingGridView:AutoSizingGridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

The used Templates with the GridViewCells use only Text elements but no imigaes are loaded.
The ItemsSource, the ListView is bound to is an ObservableCollection within the appropriate ViewModel.
My Question is the folled:
What can I do to have the incoming data displayed in real time?
It is possible that ther are up to 60(!) messages per second incoming, so over the time there can also be an amount of several 100'000 message items in the list. With each incoming new message a ScrollToEnd is triggered.
At the moment lots of high frequently incoming messages are blocking the UI completely and the visualization runs seconds up to minutes after the incoming data (depending on the amount and frequence of th incoming data).
What I Tried so far:
After some search I figured out using a VirtualizingCollection like described here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization.
This speeded up displaying and scrolling, espacially with a great amount of data, what works fine on me.
After some more search i found the suggestion using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization. This seems to be a solution but i figured out that these CollectionSynchronisation internally creates a so called ShadowList within the View, which is synchronised by the CollectionChanged events of the ItemsSource, what in turn negates the advantege I got from VirtualizingCollection<T>

You've got several overheads there like auto sizing and scroll to end. 60 a second would make your UI a blur if you sorted them out. A real time graph could work but I am very doubtful about a list view.

You need to look into a commercial library, the DevExpress grid can probably handle this.

Its tricky. What I did is reduced the update to once every 400ms. Your issue is not so much the ListView itself, but frequent calls to sync threads on the UI end. P.S. third party libs like DevExpress and/or Telerik will not really resolve your issue
